# How to handle System Error in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

When I run the following code:

```
import pandas as pd

web_states = {'Day':[1,2,3,4,5,6],    
              'Visitors': [43,53,46,78,88,24],
              'BounceRates':[65,74,99,98,45,56]}

df= pd.DataFrame(web_states)

print(df)
```

I get the following error:

> File "C:\Users\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\core_init_.py"‌​,
>   line 16, in  from . import multiarray SystemError:
>   initialization of multiarray raised unreported exception

Please advise.

Comment: after Running the above code I have got the below error,

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/KARTIK/Desktop/gangi/python/date.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
SystemError: initialization of multiarray raised unreported exception

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: `pritn` -> `print` and organize your question please... And add your comment in the question instead.

Comment: File "C:\Users\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from . import multiarray
SystemError: initialization of multiarray raised unreported exception

Comment: Correct as @TonyTannous suggested: Please add this error info instead of comments to the question. Thanks. Oh, and maybe the error is due to `BounceRates` entry only having a list with 5 entries (instead of 6 entries for the first two) - but I am not as fluent with panda as I should be ;-)

Comment: I tried with 6 entries and still its an error,

Comment: @Gangireddy could you add the whole code please ?

Comment: @ Tony, Thank you, I have added the import step as well

Answer (score 0):

Bounce Rates is too short.

**Your code:**

```
web_states = {'Day': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
              'Visitors': [43, 53, 46, 78, 88, 24],
              'BounceRates': [65, 74, 99, 98, 45]}
df = pd.DataFrame(web_states)
```

**Produces:**

```
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 5446, in extract_index
    raise ValueError('arrays must all be same length')
ValueError: arrays must all be same length
```

**Lengthen BounceRates:**

```
web_states = {'Day': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
              'Visitors': [43, 53, 46, 78, 88, 24],
              'BounceRates': [65, 74, 99, 98, 45, 0]}
df = pd.DataFrame(web_states)
print(df)
```

**Produces:**

```
   BounceRates  Day  Visitors
0           65    1        43
1           74    2        53
2           99    3        46
3           98    4        78
4           45    5        88
5            0    6        24
```